# general solution of given one solution of the differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

A point that I don't understand. The solution says The fact that $y=e^{-x}sinx$ is one solution tells us that $(r+1)^2+1$ is a factor of characteristic polynomial. How come  $(r+1)^2+1$ is figured out?

Find the general solution of given one solution of the differential equation
$$9y^{'''} + 11y^{''} + 4y^{'} - 14y = 0; y = e^{-x}sinx$$

Comment: I thought it but just now nothing makes sense related to the equation @Variable

Comment: come on if I didn't tell $(r+1)^2+1$, you wouldn't figure out

Comment: @askque can you find the general solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the characteristic polynomial of the differential equation has complex roots
$$r=\lambda\pm i\mu$$
then one solution $y=e^{rt}$ takes the form
$$y=e^{(\lambda+i\mu)t}=e^{\lambda t}e^{i\mu t} = e^{\lambda t}[\cos (\mu t) + i\sin (\mu t)]$$
Taking the real and imaginary parts of this solution gives
$$y_1=e^{\lambda t}\cos(\mu t)\qquad y_2=e^{\lambda t}\sin(\mu t)$$
The solution of your differential equation $y=e^{-x}\sin x$ means that $\lambda = -1$ and $\mu = 1$. Thus your differential equation has the roots $r=-1\pm i$. Algebraic manipulation gives
\begin{gather}
r+1=\pm i\\
(r+1)^2=-1\\
(r+1)^2+1=0
\end{gather}
Thus $(r+1)^2+1$ is a factor of the characteristic polynomial.